# full unmatch probability

Tags: probability

You have 5 distinct color envelops and 5 distinct color letters. You randomly put one letter in each envelop. What is the probability of no pair matching in color?

I can find the answer with brute force solving the complementary problem and then subtracting from 1. Looking for an elegant way to think about it, if it exists.

Comment: Search term: *derangements*

Comment: thanks @RobPratt I did look at it and it seems similar to inclusion exclusion principle. Thanks for pointing it out. I am just wondering if there is a 2-3 line argument to solve this, maybe not. For reference I found the answer to be 11/30

Comment: You can simply count cycles, which is 2-3 lines, at least for small numbers. There also does exist a formula for these, utilizing factorials are inclusion exclusion principle.

Comment: Could somebody tell me what is a good forum to post this on? I was sent here from 'quantitative finance' page. And now it appears this too is forbidden!

Comment: This would probably fit on https://math.stackexchange.com/ since it is a problem in discrete mathematics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643434/what-is-the-probability-that-no-letter-is-in-its-proper-envelope/987828#987828